# Simple Security Question: Google sheets php api credentials.json

Tags: php, security, server-side, google-sheets-api

New to php and google-sheets api.

I want to read data from google spreadsheet with php and bring it to the browser. 
So I started with the following https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php ... .

Furthermore I generated a project and credentials in google backend. 
After a few hours I ended up with a working data connection. And on my localhost everything works as expected.

The authentication in my phpFile looks like this.

```
     function getClient()
    {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName('My first PHP Google Sheets API');
      $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
      $client->setAuthConfig('myauth.json');
      $client->setAccessType('offline');
      $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

      return $client; }
```

So if I go to live server, the credentials.json is open for everyone? I am further not able to restrict the connection to my target url via api backend. All this seems very insecure. What is the best way to hide the credentials.json or restrict the connection to a url?

Many thanks in advance and sorry for my English and my skilllevel.

Comment: _"the credentials.json is open for everyone?"_ Only if you put it under the web server's document root, so don't do that.

Comment: "sorry for my English and my skilllevel". disregard anyone who puts you down for these things. you asking this question means you're trying to improve both.

Comment: @AlexHowansky. Ok, but I am using shared hosting. There is no other directory then public. Would you reccomend to us .htaccess for this?

Comment: Provided you are using linux you can use a `.htaccess` file to deny certain files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163631/ For windows, you can use a `web.config` file with a similar set of instructions

Comment: _"Would you recommend to use .htaccess for this?"_ No. All your library code, configs, scripts, docs, logs, etc., should be outside the document root. If your hosting provider doesn't allow this, find another hosting provider.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Thanks a bunch, this is probably a great time saver and a clean solution and the right direction to think about it.

Comment: @Rasclatt: Thanks you. I will for sure look in this direction.

Comment: Outside the root is safer, but using an htaccess file is commonplace and not out of the ordinary.