# Prevent direct url access to pdf links located within a protected php page

Tags: php

I am using php and I have a "login-page.php" where a user enters a User Name and Password. After a successful login the user is redirected to the "user-page.php". Within the "user-page.php" there are links to pdf files. The problem is that if someone attempts to enter directly the url link i.e. https://www.sitename.com/filefolder/filename.pdf then the pdf file is accessible. I am looking for a way to prevent that, such that any attempt to enter a direct url link to be redirected to the "login-page.php".

Comment: A detailed answer to similar problem has been given here. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163631/allow-a-php-script-access-to-pdfs-in-a-folder-but-prevent-direct-url-reference)